# How to render an enabled CMS block in phtml file in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Pretty much what the title says. I want to add the google map in a cms block and then call it in a `form.phtml` for Contact Page. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render an enabled CMS block in a phtml file in Magento 2, you can use the following code:

```
<?php
$blockId = 'your_block_identifier'; // Replace with your block identifier
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$block = $objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($blockId);
if ($block->getIsActive()) {
    echo $block->toHtml();
}
?>
```

Here's a breakdown of the code:

Define the identifier of the CMS block you want to render. This can be found in the CMS block list in the Magento admin panel.

```
$blockId = 'your_block_identifier';
```

Create an instance of the CMS block using the ObjectManager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$block = $objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($blockId);
```

Check if the block is active (enabled)

```
if ($block->getIsActive()) {
```

If the block is active, render the block's HTML using the toHtml() method.

```
echo $block->toHtml();
```

Note that using the ObjectManager directly is not best practice, and it is recommended to use dependency injection instead. Additionally, you should make sure to sanitize the $blockId input to avoid security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Override form.phtml file in your child theme and then Call your static block in that override form.phtml file:

```
<?php 
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
->setBlockId('your_block_identifier')
->toHtml();
?>
```